# website to pull data from another website and return it

Tags: c#, html, api, dom, scripting

I am writing a windows phone app that displays scores for certain sports. I contacted a particular site and have been granted permission to use their feed but they won't provide me a xml feed or api and have said that I must convert the data from their site to a format that I can use myself.

Using .Net, I had a go with downloading the site with a WebClient and searching for the information that way. This works fine.

When I deployed the app to my phone it didn't work.
I tried going to the site via my phone and it seems that my network provider has blocked the site as its over 18 (gambling I guess).

Anyway, is there away that I can do the above on my web site and have that return the data I am after?

UPDATE:
I am a .net man so I would normally try using asp.net/webservice but my site is hosted on Linux. I notice I can create rubys on rails apps. Is there anything I can do with this?

Comment: What scripting language are you using on your web site?

Comment: I have update my question as I missed some information (sorry was in a rush). I have not done anything on my website yet. The website is running on linux

Answer (score 0):

This is a really expansive answer, to do this, you have to have a piece of software to read in an API from a live score site and display it. It cant be answered in one answer, to know more about APIs take [this course](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs253).

Hope that helps you, check the course syllabus (on the same page), there is a unit called **How to Connect** which will help you. Leave a comment to tell me if it helps or if i can do anything else to make it more helpful...

Comment: @Gaz83 tell me if it helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Unfortunately there is no API to use on the site. All I have is the website url.